# Sawblade's spin stops or jitters when swiping to steer it

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, touch

- I have a 3D object, a blade, that I want to rotate **continuously**
  on the x axis, like it's cutting through something.
- I also want the player to control its *z-axis* rotation by swiping.

It's mainly working fine with no issues, but when I'm in the moving phase of the touch (swiping), the blade jitters a little and has trouble with the x-axis continuous rotation.

I've read answers on a bunch of forums, but I couldn't find one that addressed an example similar to mine because I can't use *global axis*, I believe, because if I swipe and the blade tilts to the right, for example, then the continuous rotation on the global *x-axis* would mess up the rotation.

Here's the script attached on the blade:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BladeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float continuousRotationSpeed = 600f;
    public float swipeRotationSpeed = 0.4f;
    private Quaternion initialRotation;
    private Quaternion currentRotation;
    private Vector2 touchStartPos;
    private bool isTouching = false;

    void Start()
    {
        initialRotation = transform.rotation;
        currentRotation = initialRotation;
    }

    void Update() {
        transform.Rotate(continuousRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    touchStartPos = touch.position;
                    isTouching = true;
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    if (isTouching)
                    {
                        float swipeDeltaX = touch.position.x - touchStartPos.x;
                        float swipeRotation = swipeDeltaX * swipeRotationSpeed;
                        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, swipeRotation) * currentRotation;
                        transform.rotation = targetRotation;
                        Debug.Log("BUGGGGGG");
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    isTouching = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentRotation = transform.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Here's what it looks like:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the touch moves, you apply your z twist rotation to the cached `currentRotation`, not to the actual current rotation of the blade (which was changed earlier in this `Update()` pass when `transform.Rotate()` spun it a little more). Then you overwrite the blade's current rotation with that stale value, undoing any `transform.Rotate()` calls that happened since the last time `currentRotation` was updated.

You only update `currentRotation` when no fingers are touching the screen, which effectively stalls the blade during a drag.

Try something like this instead: accumulate the rotation angles you want on x and z, then apply them all at once. A pair of degree angles `bladePose` takes over from the quaternion `currentRotation`.

```
float twistAtTouchStart;
Vector2 bladePose;

void Update() {
    bladePose.x += continuousRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    bladePose.x %= 360; // Wrap to keep the value in -360...+360
    
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                touchStartPos = touch.position;
                twistAtTouchStart = bladePose.y;
                isTouching = true;
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                if (isTouching)
                {
                    float swipeDeltaX = touch.position.x - touchStartPos.x;
                    float swipeRotation = swipeDeltaX * swipeRotationSpeed;                        
                    bladePose.y = twistAtTouchStart + swipeRotation;
                }
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                isTouching = false;
                bladePose.y %= 360;
                break;
        }
    }

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, bladePose.y)
                       * Quaternion.Euler(bladePose.x, 0, 0);
}
```